# Laravel database transactions across chained queues (Horizon/Redis)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue, laravel-horizon

I have searched for hours on this and am thinking its maybe simply not possible? Is If a job in my queue chain fails, can I rollback all database transactions that have occurred to this point.

```
DB::transaction(function () {
   ProcessPodcast::withChain([
       new OptimizePodcast,
       new ReleasePodcast
   ])->dispatch();
});
```

note: I know the above will not work when asynchronously pushing jobs to the queue, but is there a way to get this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Since queue workers are long-lived processes it is possible to utilize database transactions in chained queue jobs.

What you need to do is to **begin** a transaction on `ProcessPodcast` job's `handle` method, while making sure you **rollback** if the chain fails.

```
// ProcessPodcast parent Job

use DB; // above class, of course

public function handle()
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
}

public function failed(Exception $exception)
{
    DB::rollback();
    // Send user notification of failure, etc...
}
```

You can **commit** your transaction in any of the chained jobs.